# Logging traffic in a file?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, logging, traffic

today I'm looking for a tool that allows me to log any traffic that goes in and out.
It would be perfect if it would store that data in text files on the server.

Does anyone have a tool like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out tcpdump.

Comment: have you ever used http://www.paessler.com/prtg ? It offers much more detailed features to check/record traffic

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -w ~/my-traffic-capture.cap

-s tells it to capture the full packet which is not the default setting.

Replace eth0 with what network interface you want to capture traffic on.  You can get a list by running ifconfig.

You can view the capture in WireShark.  You could also view the capture in a text editor but since some of the data is binary, parts of it would not be intelligible.